# lg(n-i) is Omega of lg(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, quicksort

I'm trying to calculate expression below.
The point where I can't understand is line 3 to line 4.
I think after line 3, expression becomes

Sigma(i=1 to n-1) (lg(n-i))

But Can we Write that like line 4??
I'm not sure that lg(n-i) is Omega of lg(n).
And if its possible, I want Intuitive explanation too.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: lg(n-i) does not occur in this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely `log(n-i)` is not `Omega(log(n))`. A counter example is when `i = n - 1`. Or `i = n - c` for any constant `c`.

By the way, we can write for the fourth line `E[x] > sum_{k=n/2}{n} log(n/2)  = n/2 log(n/2) = Theta(nlog(n))`. Hence, `E[x]` is in `Omega(n log (n))` and the claim about the `E[x]` is correct.